# Deoloy nuxt app to digitalocean vps server

Tags: nuxt.js

I've nuxt app and I want to deploy it to digitalocean
I've made a new folder on the server and call it control-panel
here's the folder sturcture I've

```
- control-panel
-- .nuxt
--- dist
---- client
---- server
-- node_modules
-- static
-- package.json
-- nuxt.config.js
```

[image: Folder Structure]
but when I run npm run start and go to localhost:3000 it doesn't work
is there anything wrong in my folder structure ?

Comment: i have written an blog about how to setup  nuxt.js on an VPS https://blogxon.com/articles/how-to-deploy-nuxt-on-a-vps

Comment: you should go to SERVER_IP:3000 not localhost if you start it from your server

Comment: @Ifaruki Ok well check that

Comment: @Ifaruki I followed your article, but when i run npm run start it doesn't work again, I go to ```http://server_ip3000``` but it doesn't work. my .nuxt file have a dist folder inside it and then inside dist I've a client and server folders, is that the right thing ?

Comment: did you changed the host to `0.0.0.0` in your nuxt.config.js like here? https://blogxon.com/articles/how-to-deploy-nuxt-on-a-vps#upload-nuxtjs-application-to-the-server-and-run-it

Comment: Yes I do that, but still doesn't work

Comment: here is an example of the server from my blog article. this is how he ip adress should look like `http://5.83.163.62:3000/`

Comment: are you running it on universal mode or statit, client?

Comment: Its on universal mode

Comment: did it even worked on your local machine?

Comment: @Ifaruki Check the edited question I've added a screenshot of my folder structure

Comment: @Ifaruki Check the edited question I've added a screenshot of my folder structure

Comment: @Ifaruki yes it's working on my machine

Comment: i wonder that you have an `/dist` folder. if i deploy my app on univeral i dont have it

Comment: if you have git, you could mabe try to making a basic nuxt.js project to work `git clone https://github.com/ilijanovic/nuxtjs-empty-project.git` thats a completly empty project

Comment: @Ifaruki it's inside .nuxt not in the root folder